# increase the execution speed of my ionic application

Tags: android, performance, ionic-framework

is there any way to increase the execution speed of my phonegap/ionic application in my smartphone samsung galaxy S4 version 4.2.2 it's too slow !!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [crosswalk](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/)?

That's the first thing to do. After that it's more tricky. What areas are you seeing performance issues?

Lists: use collection-repeat

General: use fewer watches and use events instead.

If you give more details it'll be easier to find and fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Nathan K thanks for your reply,in fact I have problem in transition between web views I must wait at least 10 seconds or more before the transition :(

Comment: If your transitions are taking that long, you might be doing to much in the controller. It's also possible that you have a "resolve" in the route that's taking a long time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a build of your application in production.

**cordova build android --prod**

I use the Ionic Framework that uses Cordova

Follow Build information at this link
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

**ionic cordova build android --prod**